# htaccess shows directory list rewrite mode not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently working with those rewrite modes `htacess`...they works well
, Its possible to show `http://domain/username`  and `http://domain/post?id=123`

**PROBLEM**

my Site directory is seen, as I type on the browser...

```
includes/?  (http://localhot/includes/?)
account/?    (http://localhot/account/?)
```

I dont want them to be seen....this is fixed by adding an `index.php` within that specific directory....but I cant handle to put an index page in all of them....

**How do I fix this in htaccess?**

**HTACCESS**

```
#post
RewriteRule ^post/?$ account.php?p=post [L,NC,QSA] 
#user
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ account.php?p=profile&username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You can add `Options -Indexes` on top of your .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can add this directive:

```
Options -Indexes
```

on top of your .htaccess to disallow directory listing.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

#post
RewriteRule ^post/?$ account.php?p=post [L,NC,QSA]

# add trailing slash if missing from directories    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

#user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ account.php?p=profile&username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  ` What are those directives for?

Comment: In case an user creates an account as `/includes` or `/admin` or `/icons`...the `Option -indexes` send this account to `forbiden 403`

Comment: That's what `Options -Indexes` is supposed to do. It shows `403` (Forbidden) when there is no `index` file in a directory.

Comment: Yes but in case an user has an username `/icons` the scripts shows the forbidden instead of his profile...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167743/discussion-between-anubhava-and-joe).

Comment: I have made changes in answer. If doesn't work provide details what URI you're using to test, what error you're getting

Comment: it continues displayiing forbidden 403. Im currently working on localhost

Comment: Above code works perfectly fine for me on Apache.To help you further I waited on chat window for more than an hour but you didn't join.

Comment: I thought this was automatically sent _Let us continue this discussion in chat_ I'll try again and let you know